# Best way to download data from Windows Azure Table

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, azure-storage

I need to download data from windows azure table storage back to a SQL Server database inside the office network every night. There could be up to 100,000 entries in the table. What’s the most efficient way to do this (i.e. the method that costs the least)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are paying for bytes out, compressing it is the first step.  Then maybe put it in blob storage so that it can be picked up.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I moved some code to CodePlex that can help you export entities from Azure table storage: [Azure Table Query](http://azuretablequery.codeplex.com/).  If you choose Output to Compressed Xml the export file should be pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to zip/compress it before transferring.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/b33d4e52-ba20-40f8-af42-d8bbdc4069ef